# Conditional Proof with Negated Disjunctions (Biconditional Premise)

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I'm a beginner in logic, so forgive me for the inevitable incompetence!

I am trying to do a conditional proof with the sequence below, and had hoped to equivocate $\lnot(P \lor Q)$ with $\ (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$. Do I need an additional subproof to do this?

> $Q\leftrightarrow R \vdash \lnot(P \lor Q) \to \lnot (P \lor R)$

[image]

I'm also unsure whether I can apply $\land E$ to $(Q\iff\ R)$ and extract $(Q\to R)$ in a single operation, or if it requires multiple steps.

Thanks for any time taken to read my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use $\neg Q$, you can't pull it straight out of $\neg (P\vee Q)$.  If you want it, you can infer $\neg P\wedge \neg Q$ by the De Morgan law (DeM).

I'm not a huge fan of pulling apart biconditionals in natural deduction.  You can just use $\leftrightarrow E$ to replace one side with the other in a proof.  This example is harder, because you want to replace $\neg Q$ with $\neg R$ and those sentences aren't part of the biconditional.  The easiest way around it is to assume $R$, derive $\bot$ from it, then infer $\neg R$ by $\neg I$.

Here's my entire proof, when you're ready for it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Matthew! I was unaware of the biimplication intro/elim rule! I was also unsure whether I could cite De Morgan's Law in the operations column, but after consulting my textbook, it seems it's par for the course here also. (I was under the impression that I could only cite intro and elim rules along with "def" in certain cases).

Comment: @Wehage That's good news.  I'm all for proving the De Morgan rules once, but these problems can be enough of a maze even with taking derived rules of inference as granted!

Comment: The formal proof without a rule for De Morgan is actually not terribly much more complicated. You derive $\neg Q$ from $\neg(P \lor Q)$ by assuming $Q$, disjunction introduction $P \lor Q$, which contradicts $\neg(P \lor Q)$, so you can do negation introduction on the subproof with assumption $Q$ to get $\neg Q$. An analogous, inverted strategy for the reverse direction.

Comment: @lemontree I'm really impressed by your proof.  I would have guessed the proof would have been twice as long as mine instead of just one line longer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what rules you have available in your formal proof system. If you have DeMorgan as an inference rule, then you can obviously do this in one step.

If not, you'll need to do two subproofs: one to infer $\neg P $ and one to infer $\neg Q$

To get $\neg Q$: Assume $Q$, infer $P \lor Q$ using $\lor \ Intro$, and now you have a contradiction with $\neg (P \lor Q)$, and so by closing the subproof and applying $\neg \ Intro$ you can get $\neg Q$.

Same for $\neg P$

*However* ... since your goal is $\neg (P \lor r)$, I would recommend to do a proof by contradiction directly. That is: assume $P \lor R$, and then show that (using two subproofs) both $P$ and $R$ lead to a contradiction. So then yu can use proof by cases (formalized by $\lor \ Elim$) to get a contraidction, and then use $\neg \ Intro$ to get $\neg (P \lor R)$

Finally: can you infer $Q \to R$ directly from $Q \leftrightarrow R$? Again, it all dends on what formal rules the system has. Some systems allow you to do this, sure, others not.

Comment: Thank you, Bram! I will reconsider my approach. Your cautionary note on inferring a conditional from a biconditional mirrors my hesitation, but it seems to be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to introduce a conditional with an assumed negation that somehow derives another negation.  Clearly that derivation will be to introduce a negation with an assumed position that derives a contradiction...of the first assumption.

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{q\leftrightarrow r}{\fitch{\neg(p\vee q)}{\fitch{p\vee r}{~~\vdots\\p\vee q\\\bot}\\\neg(p\vee r)}\\\neg(p\vee q)\to\neg(p\vee r)}$

Now, you have assumed a disjunction with the aim of deriving a disjunction. So...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Graham, and for editing my original post! I sense that you disagree with my approach - could you expand on why assuming a disjunction to derive a disjunction within a conditional proof is a poor/inefficient strategy? I was under the impression that the standard strategy for any proposition containing a material implication as the main connective would be to assume the antecedent to construct the conditional proof.

Comment: ???  It is not inefficient.  I said it is what you should do.  Do it.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\tot\leftrightarrow$

Here is a proof using only introduction and elimination rules, without the derived De Morgan rules:
[image]

---

**The genreal strategy of getting from $\neg (P \lor Q)$ to $\neg Q$ is as follows:**
   1. Assume $Q$.
   2. If $Q$ holds, then so does $P \lor Q$. (This is disjunction introduction.)
   3. But this is a direct contradiction to the assumption that $\neg (P \lor Q)$.
   4. Conclude that the assumption $Q$ must have been wrong, i.e. derive $\neg Q$ by negation introduction on the subproof from $Q$ to $\bot$.

[image]

---

If we do the analogous for $P$, **we can derive the De Morgan rule $\neg (P \lor Q) \vdash \neg P \land \neg Q$** by simply doing a conjunction introduction on the two conclusions:

[image]

---

**The other direction of the De Morgan rule, $\neg P \land \neg Q \vdash \neg (P \lor Q)$, works as follows**:

1. Assume that $P \lor Q$ does hold.
2. Consider the case $P$, i.e. assume $P$.
3. From $\neg P \land \neg Q$, by conjunction elimination we know $\neg P$.
4. This is a contradiction to $P$.
5. Steps 2-4 analogously for $Q$.
6. Since both cases, $P$ and $Q$, leads to a contradiction, and since we assumed that at least one out of $P$ and $Q$ holds, we can conclude $\bot$ for sure. This is disjunction elimination on $P \lor Q$ and the two subproofs $P \vdash \bot$, $Q \vdash \bot$.
7. Since we derived a contradiction from the assumption $P \lor Q$, the assumption must have been wrong, and we can conclude $\neg(P \lor Q)$ by negation introduction on the whole subproof $P \lor Q \vdash \bot$.

This is what it looks like formally:

[image]

And so we avoided the De Morgan rule, which is only a derived rule and often not assumed to be part of natural deduction, by using introduction and elimination rules only.

---

> I'm also unsure whether I can apply ∧E to (Q⟺ R) and extract (Q→R) in
>   a single operation, or if it requires multiple steps.

That depends on your rule system. If you have an introduction-elimination rule pair for $\tot$, something like

```
m. | P
   ----
n. | Q
i. | Q
   ----
j. | P
k.  P <-> Q   (<->I, m-n, i-j)


m. P <-> Q
n. P
   Q          (<->E, m, n)


m. P <-> Q
n. Q
   P          (<-> E, m, n)
```

then you can derive $Q$ from $Q \tot R$, $R$ with the dedicated $\tot E$ directly, as I did on line 8 above.

If you don't have such a rule in your system, then $Q \tot R$ will be defined as $(Q \to R) \land (R \to Q)$ -- these will simply be treated as the same formula -- and you can do the desired subderivation via $\land E$ to get $R \to Q$ and $\to E$ on the on-way implication togehther with $R$ to get $Q$:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation! It seems that in our rule set for the course, we cite the definition of a biconditional in the operation column, rather than an introduction or elimination rule.